# Keep getting ValueError with numpy while trying to create array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a new array with an existing array's elements. I keep getting:ValueError: Setting void-array with object members using buffer.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

date = datetime.date(2013, 4, 5)
results = [(date,0,1,2,3), (date,5,1,5,6), (date,3,4,4,7)] 
stock_dt = np.dtype([('date', object),
                     ('open', np.int8),
                     ('high', np.int8),
                     ('low', np.int8),
                     ('close', np.int8)])

d = np.array(results, dtype=stock_dt)
matches = []
for item in d:
    if item['high'] == 1:
        matches.append(item)

rec = np.array(matches, dtype=stock_dt)

print rec
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `matches` is not a list of tuples, so you cant make a structured array out of it. Instead it's a list of structured arrays, which need to be merged back into a single structured array. You can use `numpy.lib.recfunctions.stack_arrays` for this:

```
In [21]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn

In [22]: rfn.stack_arrays(matches,usemask=False)
Out[22]: 
array([(datetime.date(2013, 4, 5), 0, 1, 2, 3),
       (datetime.date(2013, 4, 5), 5, 1, 5, 6)], 
      dtype=[('date', 'O'), ('open', 'i1'), ('high', 'i1'), ('low', 'i1'), ('close', 'i1')])
```

You could also consider doing away with the loop entirely:

```
In [23]: d[d['high'] == 1]
Out[23]: 
array([(datetime.date(2013, 4, 5), 0, 1, 2, 3),
       (datetime.date(2013, 4, 5), 5, 1, 5, 6)], 
      dtype=[('date', 'O'), ('open', 'i1'), ('high', 'i1'), ('low', 'i1'), ('close', 'i1')])
```

Which should be faster, to boot.

Comment: How could I use multiple arguments using your second answer?

Comment: What `d[d['high'] == 1]` is doing is indexing the array `d` using a list of booleans created by `d['high'] == 1`. To use multiple criteria you can use the `&` and `|` operators, like `d[(d['high'] == 1) & (d['low'] == 2)]`. Beware of making those too complex though, since it can get unreadable quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
rec = np.array(matches, dtype=stock_dt)
```

to

```
rec = np.array(matches)
```

When you're iterating over `matches` you aren't dealing with tuples anymore so you shouldn't pass `dtype=stock_dt` to `np.array` again.

Comment: I'm still getting same Error